# series solution techniques applied to 1st order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Can someone please help me on this?

I assumed $~y(x) = (a_0+a_1~x+a_2~x^2+\cdots)~$, and then calculated $~y'(x)~$. Then, I put those values in the main equation and tried solving but I don't know how to arrange the equation (especially the last or $3$rd part of the equation) in such a way that I get the results. It will be really helpful if someone shares something on this. Thanks!!

Comment: If $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n = 0, \ \forall x$, then you must have $b_n = 0$ for all $n$. Therefore, you just need to set your coefficients to zero and get a recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Starting from Newton's problem

$$y'-(1+x)y-(1-3x+x^2)=0,\quad y(0)=0$$

write the power series as

$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n, \quad y'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$$

therefore

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}-(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n-(1-3x+x^2)=0$$

or

$$a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}-(1+x)(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)\\-(1+x)\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}a_nx^n-(1-3x+x^2)=0$$

which can be used to find the coefficients for $x^0,x^1,x^2$. Next, observe that

\begin{align}\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}-(1+x)\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}a_nx^n&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(n+1)a_{n+1}x^{n}-\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}a_nx^n-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^n\\&=
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\Big[(n+1)a_{n+1}-a_n-a_{n-1}\Big]x^n - a_1x^2
\end{align}

For the second question, substitute $x=0$ to find

$$a_0-a_1-1=0$$

and then use this to find the other coefficients $a_n$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots,9$.